# How to destroy nested object from Model on Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, nested

I have a nested object Item on Order. 
Every Order has many items.

I have a setter instance method on the Order model to handle (Creating, Updating, Deleting? Items from the Order views).

I would like to delete an Item when the Item Quantity gets updated to 0 on the Edit Order view.

So far I am able to delete the item using the _destroy: checkbox on the Edit Order Form. But I would prefer to destroy it when the Quantity is 0.

Order Model:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Item Model:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
end
```

I tried to different approaches to delete the item when the quantity is 0.

1) First, I tried to use the mark_for_destruction method, but it would update the order and the item would stay there with the same quantity. 
This is the instance of the setter method that would perform that task:

```
elsif item[:id].present? && item[:qty].to_i <= 0
    order_item = self.items.find item[:id]
    order_item.mark_for_destruction
```

2) I tried to destroy it directly using .destroy, but then it throws: **Couldn't find Item with ID=308 for Order with ID=112** when reloading the show view after the update action...

```
elsif item[:id].present? && item[:qty].to_i <= 0
    order_item = self.items.find item[:id]
    order_item.destroy
```

This is the Update method on the Orders Controller that gets called.

```
def update
 respond_to do |format|
  if @order.update(order_params)
    format.html { redirect_to [:admin, @customer, @order], notice: "Order was successfully updated." }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: [:admin, @customer, @order] }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

This is the Server ROLLBACK Call when it showed the error after destroying the item.

```
SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" = $1  [["id",308]] 

Item Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE 
"items"."order_id" = $1 AND "items"."id" = 308  [["order_id", 112]]

(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you're redirecting in somewhere to the recently destroyed object. Can you add to the question your controller/s?

Comment: I updated the question and added the Orders controller that Updates the Order. It redirects to the Show Order View, I don't know why is it still looking for the recently deleted Item. Maybe I need to handle it differently on the controller? Thanks again!

Comment: @SebastianPalma I also added the ROLLBACK call on the Server that shows it is trying to Load the Item that was deleted. Maybe it helps.

Comment: is sending `_destroy` as a nested param not working?

Comment: It is working using _destroy, but I was requested to delete it when updating the quantity to 0, instead of a checkbox. I need to perform another action when updating to 0 before deleting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way. I did not considered any drawbacks, but this works:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order

  after_update :destroy_if_qty_is_zero

  private
    def destroy_if_qty_is_zero
      self.destroy if quantity == 0
    end

end
```

Try to use `Item.find(id).destroy` in case `self.destroy` does not work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out to the right direction! 
I ended up updating the Item's Qty to 0 at the moment of the Order Update, then
I ended using the after_update :destroy_if_qty_is_zero on the Order Model so it would delete the Items that had 0 as Qty.